# Getting Max value from x.y.z formatted Number

Tags: java, sorting

Is there an easy way of finding the **MAX** number from the list where number is stored in x.y.z format? e.g. To manage some system versions.

I have tried `Collection.max(list)` and that does not work.

**Sample Code:**

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("1.0.0");
    list.add("1.1.0");
    list.add("1.9.0");
    list.add("1.10.0");

    System.out.println(Collections.max(list));
}
```

**Expected:** 1.10.0
**Result:** 1.9

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this one :

```
Collections.max(myList, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
            String[] first = lhs.split("\\.");
            String[] second = rhs.split("\\.");
            for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
                if(Integer.valueOf(first[i]) > Integer.valueOf(second[i])) {
                    return 1;
                }
                if(Integer.valueOf(first[i]) < Integer.valueOf(second[i])) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Regular expression pattern `"."` will match _any_ character, not only the dot.

Comment: This is spot on. Just add \\ before dot in split method. e.g. lhs.split("\\.");

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Other solutions are similar but this one is very close to my own solution so accepting as a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well for one thing, you need to ensure that Java knows they are numbers - at the moment they're just `Strings`, and strings sort lexigraphically (i.e. in "alphabetical order").

My approach to this would be to create a small class that implements `Comparable`, which will then work automatically with sorting and comparison logic.  Something like this perhaps:

```
public class VersionNumber implements Comparable<VersionNumber> {
    public final int major;
    public final int minor;
    public final int patch;

    // Constructor etc. elided

    public int compareTo(VersionNumber other) {
        if (other.major != major) return major - other.major;
        if (other.minor != minor) return minor - other.minor;
        return patch - other.patch;
    }
}
```

Parsing the string to create instances of this class is left as an exercise to the reader!

Answer (score 2):

You may have to write a custom `Comparator` for comparing version number strings:

```
public class VersionComparator extends Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        // Get major/minor/revison numbers by splitting strings at dots
        String[] p1 = o1.split("\\.");
        String[] p2 = o2.split("\\.");

        // Compare major versions then minor then revision until a difference found
        for(int i = 0; i < (p1.length < p2.length) ? p1.length : p2.length; i++) {
            int result = Integer.valueOf(p1[i]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(p2[i]));
            if(result != 0) return result;
        }

        // Return zero if they're identical
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The you can use this comparator with the `Collections.max` function:

```
Collections.max(list, new VarsionComparator());
```

Comment: unfortunately, the string `"10"` is less than the string `"9"`

Comment: @sverre: You're right. Originally, I wanted to compare `Integer` values, but it was left out accidentally. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use version of `max` with the specified comparator:

```
System.out.println(Collections.max(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2)
    {
        StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(s1,".");
        StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(s2,".");
        int res = 0;
        String t1, t2;
        while(st1.hasMoreTokens() && st2.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            t1 = st1.nextToken(); 
            t2 = st2.nextToken();
            res = Integer.valueOf(t1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(t2));
        }
        if(res == 0)
        {
            res = st1.hasMoreTokens() ? 1 : (st2.hasMoreTokens() ? -1 : 0);
        }
        return res;

    }
    public boolean equals(Object obj) { return false; }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you 1.9 because it will not consider second number to be 10, it will treat it as 1 first and then 9

**Edit**

If you want to do it manually, then

1. Split your number on basis of "."
2. Check manually which number is greater.

Comment: I know the explanation. I'm looking for an algo to fix this. Thx for your time anyways.